# Rendered Rectangles missing in a huge WPF Control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, drawingcontext

I need a WPF `Control` with 300000000 `Width` and `Height`, on which I will draw `Rectangles`, based on some input. I am drawing the `Rectangle` on the `OnRender` of the control. For testing purpose I have put the control inside a `ScrollViewer` and am drawing `Rectangles` on each pixels from (0,0) to (1000,1000). If the `Width` & `Height` is 1000000, the `Rectangles` are drawn properly, shown below, (the `Rectangles` are plotted on all the pixels from (0,0) to (1000,1000), so it looks like the on in the below link)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/950012

But If I increase the size to 3000000, few lines are missing in the drawing like below,
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/950018

My Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScrollViewer"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <waferControl:WaferMapControl x:Name="WaferControl"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Width="30000000"
                                Height="30000000"
                                Margin="10"
                                ColumnCount="{Binding WaferInfo.ColumnCount}"
                                RowCount="{Binding WaferInfo.RowCount}"
                                SelectedCells="{Binding SelectedCellCollection}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am using the following code in `OnRender` of `WaferMapControl`.

```
private void RenderBackgroud(IEnumerable lists`enter code here`)
{
    using (DrawingContext dc = _backgroundDv.RenderOpen())
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = Brushes.Black;

        if (brush.CanFreeze)
            brush.Freeze();

        foreach (GridCellInfo cellInfo in lists)
        {
            double length = cellInfo.GridRange;

            var point = new Point(
                cellInfo.RowIndex + 1,
                ActualHeight - cellInfo.ColumnIndex  - length);

            RenderBackgroud(dc, point, brush, length);
        }
    }
}

private void RenderBackgroud(DrawingContext dc, Point point, Brush brush, double length)
{
   var rect = new Rect(point, new Size(length, length));

   dc.DrawRectangle(brush, null, rect);
}
```

The `cellInfo` contains the x,y coordinates. The point calculation is done to draw from the bottom left. The length is 1 in my sample.

Can someone help me out, what is the issue here. Let me know if you require anything from my side.

Comment: do you have a full reproducing code?

Comment: then please share it

Comment: Perhaps this is being caused by antialiasing. Try turning it off (something like `this.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased)` before looping to draw the rectangles)

Comment: @MatthewWatson not working. still the same.

Comment: @SimonMourier you can download the code from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aout7a-ZRaxMiiiDpckw_lIvsYnN)

Comment: My guess is it's 100% by design. Since you always displays the same number of rows with a rectangle of 1 pixel high per row (like a line), if you stretch the control vertically, it will just stretch the space between the rectangles/lines.

Comment: @SimonMourier I dont think that would be the issue as the Control size is increased both vertically and horizontally. And also it does not work only if the size is increased beyond 10000000.